# Orchestrating Spring Boot CrudRepositories with foreign key relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a Spring Boot application that will use Hibernate/JPA to persist between the app and a MySQL DB.

Here we have the following JPA entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Type(type="uuid-binary")
    private UUID refId;
}

@Entity(name = "contacts")
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column=@Column(name="contact_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "refId", column=@Column(name="contact_ref_id"))
})
public class Contact extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "contact_given_name")
    private String givenName;

    @Column(name = "contact_surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "contact_phone_number")
    private String phone;
}

@Entity(name = "assets")
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column=@Column(name="asset_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "refId", column=@Column(name="asset_ref_id"))
})
public class Asset extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "asset_location")
    private String location;
}

@Entity(name = "accounts")
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column=@Column(name="account_id")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "refId", column=@Column(name="account_ref_id"))
})
public class Account extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "contact_id")
    private Contact contact;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "asset_id", referencedColumnName = "asset_id")
    private Asset asset;

    @Column(name = "account_code")
    private String code;
}
```

And the `@RestController`, where an `Account` instance will be POSTed (to be created):

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {
    @Query("FROM accounts where account_code = :accountCode")
    public Account findByCode(@Param("accountCode") String accountCode);
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts")
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createNewAccount(@RequestBody Account account) {
        // Do some stuff maybe

        accountRepository.save(account);
    }
}
```

So the idea here is that "Account JSON" will be sent to this controller where it will be deserialized into an `Account` instance and (somehow) persisted to the backing MySQL. My concern is this: `Account` is a composition (via foreign keys) of several other entities. Do I need to:

- Either create `CrudRepository` impls for each of these entities, and then orchestrate `save(...)` calls to those repositories such that the "inner-entitities" get saved first before the "outer" `Account` entity?; or
- Do I just save the `Account` entity (via `AccountRepository.save(account)`) and Hibernate/JPA automagically takes care of creating all the inner/dependendent entities for me?

What would the code/solution look like in either scenario? And how do we specify values for `BaseEntity#id` when it is an auto-incrementing PK in the DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on your design and specific use cases, and what level of flexibility you want to keep. Both ways are used in practice.

In most CRUD situations, you would rather save the account and let Hibernate save the entire graph (the second option). Here you usually have another case which you didn't mention, and it is updating of the graph, which you would probably do the same way, and actually the Spring's repository `save` method does it: if the entity is a new (transient) one, it persists it, otherwise it merges it.

All you need to do is to tell Hibernate to cascade the desired entity lifecycle operations from the `Account` to the related entities:

```
@Entity
...
public class Account extends ... {
    @OneToOne(..., cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    ...
    private Contact contact;

    @OneToOne(..., cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    ...
    private Asset asset;

    ...
}
```

However, you pay the penalty of reloading the object graph from the db in case of merge operation, but if you want everything done automatically, Hibernate has no other way to check what has actually changed, other than comparing it with the current state in the db.

Cascade operations are applied always, so if you want more flexibility, you obviously have to take care of things manually. In that case, you would omit cascade options (which is your current code), and save and update the parts of the object graph manually in the order that does not break any integrity constraints.

While involving some boilerplate code, manual approach gives you flexibility in more complex or performance-demanding situations, like when you don't want to load or reinitialize the parts of the detached graph for which you know that they are not changed in some context in which you save it.

For example, let's assume a case where there are separate web service methods for updating account, contact and asset. In the case of the account method, with cascading options you would need to load the entire account graph just to merge the changes on the account itself, although contact and asset are not changed (or worse, depending on how you do it, you may here revert changes on them made by somebody else in their dedicated methods in the meantime if you just use the detached instances contained in the account).

Regarding auto-generated ids, you don't have to specify them yourself, just take them from the saved entities (Hibernate will set it there). It is important to take the result of the repository's `save` method if you plan to use the updated entity afterwards, because `merge` operation always returns the merged copy of the passed-in instance, and if there are any newly persisted associated entity instances in the updated detached graph, their ids will be set in the copy, and the original instances are not modified.